# TC (tynicore) apache server

Tags: linux, apache, веб-сервер, lamp

Устанавливаю на машину tc (tynicore). Машинка старая: ОЗУ 512 Мб SIMM 133, 128Мб DOM в качестве диска (вроде 7Мб/сек).
Нужен простой "домашний/отладочный" сервер с Апачем (самый базовый LAMP), ресурсов этой машинки для такой задачи придостаточно (никаких тяжеловесов не планируется от слова совсем).

**Про предложение поставить форточки/Ubuntu/прочие_красивые_варианты_требующие_более_128Мб_диска скажу сразу:** мне не нужен перегруженный графическим ядром выплеск чьей-то креативной мысли. Мне нужен СЕРВЕР, а не игровая машина. TC на эту роль подходит идеально, у него всё есть, надо только найти, поставить, настроить (включая автозапуск) и запустить компоненты...

**Что конкретно надо:** LAMP (можно некрофилию, но желательно вменяемый PHP5, MySQL не самый затёртый, умеющий FLOAT, INT32, CHAR, TEXT и DECIMAL, а также JOIN включая "вложенные" подзапросы), FTP (простейший, в тырнет выводоить не планируется), готовое пространство под проектики (директория www) и всё...

**Для тех, кто всё-ещё почему-то думает, что речь о сервере для ВК/Google/Яndex/Joomla/WordPress и прочего:** ***НЕТ!*** Сервер для своих проектов, вручную писюкаемых в блокнотике (gEdit если быть точным, но это не важно) с пространствами в килобайты (файлы и база).

Также целесообразность openSSH для такой совсем домашней машинки (без шара в тырнет, т.е. до первого роутера, никаких пробросов портов (есть 1 от статического IP "центральной" машины) и пр. Только из внутренней сети по локальному IP от локального IP).

Наставления, пожелания и подсказки гуру приветствуются.

Нашёл некую "инструкцию" по решению вопроса:

```
tce-load -wi openssh
cd /usr/local/etc/ssh/
sudo cp ssh_config.orig ssh_config
sudo cp sshd_config.orig sshd_config
sudo /usr/local/etc/init.d/openssh start
sudo passwd tc
sudo echo '/usr/local/etc/ssh' >> /opt/.filetool.lst 
sudo echo '/etc/shadow' >> /opt/.filetool.lst
sudo chown root:staff /opt/bootlocal.sh
sudo chmod 775 /opt/bootlocal.sh
sudo echo '/usr/local/etc/init.d/openssh start &' >> /opt/bootlocal.sh
filetool.sh -b
tce-load -wi mariadb mariadb-10.5
mkdir /opt/mysql
!   cp -Lr /usr/local/mysql/data /opt/mysql/
!   sudo rm -rf /opt/mysql/data/ib*
!   printf '\n# MySQL\nrm -rf /usr/local/mysql/data\nln -s /opt/mysql/data /usr/local/mysql/data\nln -sf /opt/mysql/my.cnf /usr/local/mysql/my.cnf\nsudo -u tc /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe 2>&1 > /dev/null &' >> /opt/bootlocal.sh
sudo printf "\nTERM="linux"\nexport TERM" >> "/home/tc/.profile"
sudo echo '/home/tc/.profile' >> /opt/.filetool.lst
filetool.sh -b
sudo reboot
---
mysql -u root
CREATE DATABASE basename;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON basename.* TO "user"@"localhost" IDENTIFIED BY "password";
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
exit
tce-load -wi apache2-mod-php5
printf '\n# Apache\nrm -rf /usr/local/apache2/htdocs\nln -s /opt/apache2/htdocs /usr/local/apache2/htdocs\nln -sf /opt/apache2/httpd.conf /usr/local/apache2/conf/\napachectl start' >> /opt/bootlocal.sh
mkdir -p /opt/apache2/htdocs
sudo cp /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf /opt/apache2/
sudo vi /opt/apache2/httpd.conf 
#ServerName 127.0.0.1
touch /opt/apache2/htdocs/.htaccess
echo 'DirectoryIndex index.php index.html' > /opt/apache2/htdocs/.htaccess
sudo vi /opt/apache2/httpd.conf
# <Directory "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs"> ==> Change the AllowOverride line from None to All.
filetool.sh -b
sudo reboot
```

Но столкнулся с непрятными сюрпризами...

1. mariadb не находит, зато находит mariadb-10.5
2. После установки с консоли нет директории /usr/local/mysql/
3. После установки с утилиты-установщика нет в /usr/local/mysql/ директории под именем data
4. После "входа" в MySQL (sudo mysql -u root) не хочет оттуда выходить (exit ничего не делает, пробовал quit, та-же фигня). Но это ладно - закрываем консоль и порядок... Вроде...

Учитывая косяки до установки Apache дело не дошло (БД не прописана на запуск, я фиг знаю как её заставить запускаться).

Восклицательными знаками выделил "нехорошие" места. Сама инструкция чутка подправлена, изменена mariadb на mariadb-10.5, а также добавлены 2 строки изменения прав доступа к bootlocal.sh (иначе не было возможности в него что-либо как-либо занести. Даже от sudo).
И да, это не .sh скрипт, это именно инструкция (для печати ручками).

Есть где более рабочая инструкция, что плясать и куда в бубен бить?

P.S. Mануальные поиски не дали результатов - потому сюда и пишу (привет любителям слать в Гуголь)...

Comment: А в сторону `alpine linux` не смотрел?

Comment: @don-rumata он 130Мб в чистом весе хочет, диск 128. Не влезет.
Как я понял tinycore скорее BSD, чем линукс.
Из всех известных мне ОС с возможностью LAMP (FAMP) tinycore больше всего подходит...
Но если есть другие подобные варианты - я весь во внимании.

Comment: А `SliTaz` тоже большой?

Comment: Спасибо, @don-rumata, вот SliTaz подходит :)
Есть где инструкция по установке в него Apache (или подобного) с модулем PHP?
Почитал про него, на борту (вроде) SSH (FTP) и SQLite. Это радует.
И по ресурсам совсем не требователем (от i486 и 16Мб ОЗУ при загрузке с харда).

Comment: Ну конфиг у апача в слитазе не отличается от конфига апача в убунте, если это не суперразные версии.

Comment: Долго со слитазом мучался... С оболочкой он хочем намного больше, чем 128Мб. Без неё не хочет подключаться к тырнету... В графической оболочке ругается, что версия ядра слишком старая для версии установщика (что странно, всё с одного образа диска ставилось с оф сайта)... По ТС проблема явно в изменениях философии Машки, дирректорий и прав (не даёт запускать от ТС, недостаточно прав. От суперюзверя ожидаемо тоже (безопасность)...